# Recursive variadic template with empty parameter pack (to avoid duplication for base case)

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

I am experimenting with C++ recursive templates and I do not know why my template is not working.

Say I want to define a recursive function that takes a variable number of arguments (for different types).

I've have looked at many examples of variadic templates, and all that I've seen so far use a separate template specialisation to specify the base case.

However, I think it would be nicer (in some cases at least) to use a single template, that defines the base case as well as the recursive cases.

I think this approach is especially nice if you have a lot of common logic in the function, which you would have to duplicate for your base case instance (exact same code in two different places).

The second template in the example below is supposed to be my solution. I would think that this template should be functioning on it's own. However this is not the case.

Without the first template, the code does not compile:

```
error: no matching function for call to
      'add_elems'
        return head[i] + add_elems(i, second, tail...);
                         ^~~~~~~~~
in instantiation of function
      template specialization 'add_elems<double, std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> >>' requested here

...
```

Apparently the template braks when `tail` consists of just one parameter. But shouldn't `add_elems(i, second, tail...)` then still be valid for the template 
`template<typename V, typename S, typename... T>
    V add_elems(size_t i, const std::vector<V>& head, const S& second, const T&... tail)` with an empty `tail`?

I do not know if this is compiler dependent, but I am using clang.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

/* This template is the exact same as the below template with an
      empty parameter pack as tail. I want my code to be working 
      without this specialisation */
template<typename V, typename S>
V add_elems(size_t i, const std::vector<V>& head, const S& second)
{
    /* Imagine some more code here */
    return head[i] + second[i];
}

template<typename V, typename S, typename... T>
V add_elems(size_t i, const std::vector<V>& head, const S& second, const T&... tail)
{
    /* Imagine some more code here (the same as above) */

    if (sizeof...(tail) > 0)
        return head[i] + add_elems(i, second, tail...);
    else
        return head[i] + second[i];
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> a({1, -3, -3});
    std::vector<double> b({2, -2, 1});
    std::vector<double> c({4, -4, -11});
    std::vector<double> d({4, 10, 0});

    std::cout << "Result: " << add_elems(0, a, b, c, d);
    std::cout << " ," << add_elems(1, a, b, c, d);
    std::cout << " ," << add_elems(2, a, b, c, d);
}
```

Comment: Define "is not working", and "breaks".

Comment: `if (sizeof...(tail) > 0)` is a run-time evaluation, not compile-time. What version of Clang are you using?

Comment: @AndyG: What do you mean by "a run-time evaluation"? `sizeof` doesn't evaluate its arguments at all, and this is just `sizeof...(T)`.

Comment: @AndyG ah, but then at compile time, shouldn't `if (sizeof...(tail) > 0)
        return head[i] + add_elems(i, second, tail...);` still be converted to:
`if (sizeof...([]) > 0)
        return head[i] + add_elems(i, second);`
E.g. conditional infinite recursion (with a condition that is always false)?
I am using `Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.38)` btw.

Comment: No it doesn't work like that.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition: I mean the `if` is not `constexpr` All code paths would need to be evaluated, and when OP removes the base specialization things go awry specifically because of `return head[i] + add_elems(i, second, tail...);`

Comment: @AndyG: Ah right yes. Slightly different but I get what you mean now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your `if` statement is not `constexpr`. Meaning that all code paths need to be compilable for every potential call to `add_elems`

This means that eventually you end up at a case where `tail` is just one element, and the compiler needs to evaluate `add_elems(size_t&, const, std::vector<double>&)`, which doesn't exist because there's no `second` argument.

**If** you were able to have a [`constexpr if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if) statement, then this would all work nicely because the compiler *wouldn't even compile the bad branch* when it evaluates to false, and therefore wouldn't look for a nonexistent function:

```
template<typename V, typename S, typename... T>
V add_elems(size_t i, const std::vector<V>& head, const S& second, const T&... tail)
{
    if constexpr (sizeof...(tail) > 0)
        return head[i] + add_elems(i, second, tail...);
    else
        return head[i] + second[i];
}
```

[Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/AFJdBKo0WLAufcTT) (requires **Clang 3.9.1** or greater and `-std=c++1z` option.)

For what it's worth, if you have access to C++17, you can achieve this with a [unary right fold](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold):

```
template<typename... T>
decltype(auto) add_elems(size_t i, const T&... elems)
{
    return (elems[i] + ...);
}
```

[Demo 2](https://wandbox.org/permlink/H3LSe6u0uohJ8hOm) (requires **Clang 3.6.0** or greater and `-std=c++1z` option.)

Answer (score 2):

Waiting for C++17, I propose a C++11 not-so-nice solution, following the AndyG one

```
template <typename T0, typename ... T>
auto add_elems2 (size_t i, T0 const & elem0, T const & ... elems)
   -> decltype(elem0[i])
 {
   using unused=int[];

   auto ret = elem0[i];

   unused a { (ret += elems[i], 0)... };

   return ret;
 }
```

Comment: Yeah simple expansion is nice. I never found it very readable, though. Heck, I don't find fold expressions particularly readable either despite their usefulness. I might actually advocate OP keep the base template/variadic template pattern (with some slight modification) because it's likely more comprehensible to them/their team.

Comment: @AndyG - I'm agree: this solution isn't elegant (isn't readable) at all. Waiting for C++17 that permit a lot clearer code.

Answer (score 1):

As the error message says, the problem you have at the moment is that the call `add_elems(i, second, tail...)` doesn't match the definition of the function, in the case where tail is empty. Even though the boolean expression in the if statement is constexpr, until c++1z the whole body of the function has to be valid.

@AndyG provides one way that c++1z can deal with this issue, another is with `if constexpr`, which allows a "compile time branch". Either of those allow you to have one (primary) specialisation of your template.

```
// Only in c++1z
template<typename V, typename S, typename... T>
V add_elems(size_t i, const std::vector<V>& head, const S& second, const T&... tail)
{
    /* Imagine some more code here (the same as above) */

    if constexpr (sizeof...(tail) > 0)
        return head[i] + add_elems(i, second, tail...); // this is not required to be valid when the if is false
    else
        return head[i] + second[i]; // this is not required to be valid when the if is true (but it is happens to be valid anyway)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As many have noted, this is easy in C++1z.  It can be done in C++14, it is just hard.

```
template<class True, class False>
True pick( std::true_type, True t, False ) {
  return std::move(t);
}
template<class True, class False>
False pick( std::false_type, True, False f ) {
  return std::move(f);
}
template<bool b>
constexpr std::integral_constant<bool, b> bool_k;


template<typename V, typename S, typename... T>
V add_elems(size_t i, const std::vector<V>& head, const S& second, const T&... tail)
{
  return
    pick( bool_k<(sizeof...(tail)>0)>,
      [&](const auto&... tail)->V{
        // tail... template argument hides function argument above:
        return head[i] + add_elems(i, second, tail...);
      },
      [&]()->V{
        return head[i] + second[i];
      }
    )
    ( tail... );
};
```

we do a compile time dispatch using `pick` to one of two lambdas.

These lambdas take the part of the code that varies by `auto` parameter, which makes them templates.  So long as they are valid for some set of `auto` parameters (even ones they are "never called with"), they are legal C++.

What we have readly done is hide the two overloads within the lambdas.  As C++11 doesn't have template lambdas, this "hidden overload" technique won't work in C++11.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Boost.Hana](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/hana/doc/html/index.html#tutorial-integral-branching) to emulate the behaviour of `if constexpr` in C++14. For example:

```
template <typename...>
struct is_empty_pack : hana::integral_constant<bool, false> {};
template <>
struct is_empty_pack<> : hana::integral_constant<bool, true> {};

template <typename T, typename... Ts>
auto sum(T const& t, Ts const&... ts) {
  return hana::if_(is_empty_pack<Ts...>{},
    [](auto const& t) { return t; },
    [](auto const& t, auto const&... ts) { return t + sum(ts...); }
  )(t, ts...);
}
```